# Skip custom signin page from middleware

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I want to skip middleware logic for signin page, but inable to do so, if i delete the middleware it works fine.
Here is my middleware code

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export default withAuth(
    // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
    function middleware(req) {
        console.log("Request Path:", req.nextUrl.pathname);
        if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/auth/signIn") {
            return NextResponse.next();
        }
        if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_ENABLED === "true") {
            const decodedToken = jwt_decode(req.nextauth?.token?.accessToken);
            if (!req.nextauth.user) {
                // Return early if not authenticated
                return;
            }
            const scope = decodedToken?.scope;
            const currentUrlPath = req.nextUrl.pathname;
            if (
                !scope ||
                (!scope.includes("studio_scope") &&
                    !scope.includes("admin_scope") &&
                    !scope.includes("superuser_scope"))
            ) {
                return new NextResponse("You are not authorized! Please contain system administrator");
            }

            if (
                scope.includes("admin_scope") &&
                ["/ontology", "/projects", "/user-management"].some((sc) => currentUrlPath?.includes(sc))
            ) {
                return new NextResponse("You are not authorized to access this resource!");
            }

            if (scope.includes("studio_scope") && currentUrlPath === "/skills") {
                return new NextResponse("You are not authorized to access this resource!");
            }
        }
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized: (params) => {
                return !!params.user;
            }
        },
    },
);
```

I have made these changes in my middleware file
here are my nextauth file changes, using keyclock as a provider

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const getDomainWithoutSubdomain = (url) => {
    const urlParts = new URL(url).hostname.split(".");

    return urlParts
        .slice(0)
        .slice(-(urlParts.length === 4 ? 3 : 2))
        .join(".");
};

const useSecureCookies = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL.startsWith("https://");
const cookiePrefix = useSecureCookies ? "__Secure-" : "";
const hostName = getDomainWithoutSubdomain(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);

const refreshAccessToken = async (token) => {
    try {
        if (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) > token.refreshTokenExpired) {
            return null;
        }
        const details = {
            client_id: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            grant_type: ["refresh_token"],
            refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
        };
        const formBody = [];
        Object.entries(details).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
            const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(value);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        });
        const formData = formBody.join("&");
        const url = `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL}/realms/${process.env.AUTH_ISSUER_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            },
            body: formData,
        });

        const refreshedTokens = await response.json();
        if (!response.ok) throw refreshedTokens;

        return {
            ...token,
            accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
            expires_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + refreshedTokens.expires_in,
            refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            ...token,
            error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
        };
    }
};

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        KeycloakProvider({
            clientId: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.AUTH_ISSUER + "/" + process.env.AUTH_ISSUER_REALM,
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: `${cookiePrefix}next-auth.session-token`,
            options: {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: "lax",
                path: "/",
                secure: useSecureCookies,
                domain: hostName == "localhost" ? hostName : "." + hostName, // add a . in front so that subdomains are included
            },
        },
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.accessToken = token?.accessToken;
            const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token?.accessToken);
            session.id_token = token?.id_token;
            session.scope = decodedToken?.scope;
            return session;
        },
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
                token.id_token = account.id_token;
                token.expires_at = account.expires_at;
                token.refresh_token = account.refresh_token;
                token.refreshTokenExpired = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + account.refresh_expires_in;
            } else if (token) {
                const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                if (token.expires_at < now) {
                    let refreshedToken = await refreshAccessToken(token);
                    if (refreshedToken) {
                        token.accessToken = refreshedToken.accessToken;
                        token.expires_at = refreshedToken.expires_at;
                        token.refresh_token = refreshedToken.refreshToken;
                    }
                }
            }
            return token;
        },
    },
});
```

If I delete the middleware signin page works fine.
else it continuously loads.